# Single query for terms aggregation with or without nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to get an aggregation of all the unique values for a field.
I found that this query works well for a "simple" field with no nested type in the json path.

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "myResult": {
      "terms": { "field": "school.student.name" }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

However, when one of the objects in the path is of nested type, I have to make a different request. Let say student is nested just for the example, then I change the query like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "myResult": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "school.student"
      }
      "aggs": {
        "myResult2": {
           "terms": { "field": "school.student.name" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

However, in my app, I only have the json path such as "school.student.name" but I do not know if there is a nested object, and who is the nested.
I did not find any solution to make a single request that could work to handle both case, and I end up with a configuration file where I have to explicitly list all the nested path that I have in my elastic database, to build the correct request. However, if I have hundreds of fields, this is not maintainable.
Does elastic really do not implement such a simple and basic feature?

I just want to get all unique values corresponding to a json path in my elastic database.

Would you have a better solution than the config file?

Comment: You can also always send both (simple + nested), that way you'll always get a response for one of the fields.

Comment: This solution would be suitable if the nested part was always at the same level. I have to specify its jsonpath, right ?
So If I have "school.student.name" where student is the nested, I have to indicate the nested path "school.student". But it could be at another level for other fields, such as "university.department.professor.name" where the nested could be for example "professor". Then, I would have to specify that the nested is ""university.department.professor".

Comment: Well, the first step towards efficient querying is to actually know your mapping and why fields are mapped the way they are. There's no magic behind all this.

Comment: Do you think that my solution using a configuration file containing all the nested path is correct ? The file would contain "school.student" and "university.department.professor". So if I have the field "school.student.name", I know precisely where the nested is and I can query it. However, if I have thousands of fields and the elastic mapping changes, it will be a pain to change it all.

Comment: You should directly retrieve the mapping as it is currently stored in ES, parse it and you'd always have the right fields.

Comment: Oh you're right, this should be much better. Thanks a lot for your time and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for configuration file, you should directly retrieve the mapping as it is currently stored in ES, parse it and you'd always have the right fields.